# Using reduce to calculate the sum of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to compute the sum of the weight of an array of object with children, however I think I am doing it the wrong way. I am trying to present a list of parcels using a searchable dropdown package. individuals should be able to select parcel categories and see the total weight of the parcels selected within a text tag. Below are my codes

parcelCategories.js

```
    export const ParcelCategories = [
      {
        name: "Men's",
        id: 0,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Clothing',
            id: 10,
            Weight: 4,
          },
          {
            name: 'Shirts',
            id: 11,
            Weight: 3,
          },
          {
            name: 'Jackets & Coats',
            id: 13,
            Weight: 2,
          },
          {
            name: 'Hoodie & Sweatshirts',
            id: 14,
            Weight: 4,
          },
          {
            name: 'Shorts',
            id: 15,
            Weight: 4,
          },
          {
            name: 'Jeans',
            id: 17,
            Weight: 2,
          },
          {
            name: 'Sneakers',
            id: 18,
            Weight: 1,
          },
          {
            name: 'Loafers & Slip-ons',
            id: 19,
            Weight: 4,
          },
        ]
      }
    ];
```

App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import {
      Platform,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      ScrollView,
      Switch,
      TouchableWithoutFeedback,
      TouchableOpacity,
      ActivityIndicator,
      Dimensions,
      LayoutAnimation,
    } from 'react-native'
    import SectionedMultiSelect from 'react-native-sectioned-multi-select'
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
    import ParcelCategories from './parcelCategories'


    const tintColor = '#174A87'

    export default class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          items: null,
          loading: false,
          selectedItems: [],
          selectedItems2: [],
          selectedItemObjects: [],
          currentItems: [],
          showDropDowns: false,
          single: false,
          readOnlyHeadings: false,
          highlightChildren: false,
          selectChildren: false,
          hasErrored: false,
        };
        this.termId = 100;
      }

      onSelectedItemsChange = (selectedItems) => {
        const filteredItems = selectedItems.filter(val => !this.state.selectedItems2.includes(val));
        this.setState({ selectedItems: filteredItems });
        console.log(selectedItems);
      }

      onConfirm = () => {
        this.setState({ currentItems: this.state.selectedItems });
      }
      onCancel = () => {
        this.SectionedMultiSelect._removeAllItems();

        this.setState({
          selectedItems: this.state.currentItems,
        });
        console.log(this.state.selectedItems);
      }

      customChipsRenderer = (props) => {
        console.log('props', props);
        return (
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', padding: 15, }}>
          <Text>Selected:</Text>
          {props.selectedItems.map((singleSelectedItem) => {
            const item = this.SectionedMultiSelect._findItem(singleSelectedItem)

            if (!item || !item[props.displayKey]) return null;

            return (
              <View key={item[props.uniqueKey]} style={{ flex: 0,marginRight: 5, padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'orange' }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.SectionedMultiSelect._removeItem(item) }}>
              <Text>{item[props.displayKey]}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          })}
          </View>
        );
      }

      onSelectedItemObjectsChange = (selectedItemObjects) => {
        this.setState({ selectedItemObjects });
        console.log(selectedItemObjects);
      }

      renderSelectText = () => {
        const { selectedItemObjects } = this.state;

        return selectedItemObjects.length ?
          `I like ${selectedItemObjects.map((item, i) => {
            let label = `${item.name}, `;
            if (i === selectedItemObjects.length - 2) label = `${item.name} and `;
            if (i === selectedItemObjects.length - 1) label = `${item.name}.`;
            return label;
          }).join('')}`
          :
          'Select a parcel';
      }

      addValues = () => {
        const total = parcelCategories.reduce((result, { children: { value } }) => result.value + value, 0)
        return total;
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" style={{ backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8' }} contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                React native sectioned multi select example.

            </Text>
            <SectionedMultiSelect
              items={parcelCategories}
              ref={SectionedMultiSelect => this.SectionedMultiSelect = SectionedMultiSelect}
              uniqueKey="id"
              subKey="children"
              displayKey="name"
              iconKey="icon"
              modalWithTouchable
              customChipsRenderer={this.customChipsRenderer}
              chipsPosition="top"
              showDropDowns={this.state.showDropDowns}
              expandDropDowns={this.state.expandDropDowns}
              readOnlyHeadings={this.state.readOnlyHeadings}
              onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
              onSelectedItemObjectsChange={this.onSelectedItemObjectsChange}
              onCancel={this.onCancel}
              onConfirm={this.onConfirm}
              selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
              colors={{ primary: this.state.selectedItems.length ? 'forestgreen' : 'crimson', }}
              itemNumberOfLines={3}
              selectLabelNumberOfLines={3}
              styles={{
                selectedItemText: {
                  color: 'blue',
                },
                selectedSubItemText: {
                   color: 'blue',
                },
              }}
            />
            <View style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', height: 70 }}>
            <Text>{this.renderSelectText()}</Text>
            <Text>{this.addValues()}Kg</Text>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      center: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 30,
      },
      container: {
        paddingTop: 40,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
        color: '#333',
      },
      border: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#dadada',
        marginBottom: 20,
      },
      heading: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 20,
      },
      label: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    })
```

I dont seem to be getting it right, I want to be able to sum up the total weight based on the parcel categories chosen

Answer (score 0):

You need first to map to keep only Weight :

```
ParcelCategories[0].children.map(function(item) { return item.Weight }).reduce(function(curval, newval) { return curval + newval })
```

Comment: It is throwing an unexpected token, expected: (fatal)

Comment: Sorry I did a mix between old and new JS syntax. Try again ?I updated

Comment: I think its getting there, but its just returning the first value under the category

Comment: You mean it returns 4 here ? (First weight property of your array)

Comment: exactly
its not computing it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vreLaxj1/ I just tried the code, it computes your sum properly

Comment: oh okay, Yeah it did
thanks
but I think you misunderstood me or I dint explain it properly, its a react native app and i want only selected parcels to be computed, not a total sum of all parcels in the array

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to fix your import statement:

```js
// needs braces if you aren't exporting default
import { ParcelCategories } from './parcelCategories'
```

And in your `SectionedMultiSelect` props:

```js
<SectionedMuliSelect
  items={ParcelCategories}
  // ...the rest of the code
```

If you're using `ParcelCategories` as the items in the `SectionedMultiSelect`, you should be able to do this:

```
addValues = () => {
  const { selectedItemObjects } = this.state
  const total = selectedItemObjects.reduce((result, { Weight }) => result += Weight, 0)
  return total
}
```

Comment: thanks, I think you fully understand what I am trying to achieve, but its returning a value of 0

Comment: @vincentO I have a better understanding of how `SectionedMultiSelect` works now, and I've updated the code accordingly

Comment: It is throwing an unexpected token, expected: (fatal)

Comment: Can you try the alternate method I just finished writing?

Comment: you are a life saver, been stuck on this for the past 4 days.
thank you